# Specified Remote Server is not running in WSO2 Developer Studio 2.1.0

Tags: wso2, wso2-integration-studio

when I try to commit the changes made to a registry resource in WSO2 Developer Studio 2.1.0 I see this error:
Specified Remote Server is not running.

message code: ERROR_IN_RESTORING, parameters:{path:/_system/config/gestion_tesis/servicioProfesor/secuencias/centralAssets,registry url:https://iesb.uci.cu/t/ptesisesb.cdae.uci.cu/registry,username:admin@ptesisesb.cdae.uci.cu}

In the log file I see this:

```
!ENTRY org.wso2.developerstudio.eclipse.greg.base 4 0 2013-01-15 11:01:14.095
!MESSAGE Transport error: 405 Error: Method Not Allowed
!STACK 0
org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Transport error: 405 Error: Method Not Allowed
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPSender.handleResponse(HTTPSender.java:308)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPSender.sendViaPost(HTTPSender.java:194)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPSender.send(HTTPSender.java:75)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.CommonsHTTPTransportSender.writeMessageWithCommons(CommonsHTTPTransportSender.java:450)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.CommonsHTTPTransportSender.invoke(CommonsHTTPTransportSender.java:277)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.send(AxisEngine.java:443)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.send(OutInAxisOperation.java:406)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.executeImpl(OutInAxisOperation.java:229)
    at org.apache.axis2.client.OperationClient.execute(OperationClient.java:165)
    at org.wso2.carbon.core.services.authentication.AuthenticationAdminStub.login(AuthenticationAdminStub.java:311)
    at org.wso2.developerstudio.eclipse.greg.resource.authorization.ResourceAdmin.isUserAuthenticate(ResourceAdmin.java:153)
    at org.wso2.developerstudio.eclipse.greg.base.ui.dialog.CredentialsDialog.okPressed(CredentialsDialog.java:234)
    at org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.Dialog.buttonPressed(Dialog.java:472)
    at org.wso2.developerstudio.eclipse.greg.base.ui.dialog.CredentialsDialog.buttonPressed(CredentialsDialog.java:223)
    at org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.Dialog$2.widgetSelected(Dialog.java:624)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:234)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1053)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4066)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3657)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.runEventLoop(Window.java:825)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Window.java:801)
    at org.wso2.developerstudio.eclipse.greg.base.ui.util.SWTControlUtils.requestCredentials(SWTControlUtils.java:82)
    at org.wso2.developerstudio.eclipse.greg.manager.local.checkout.actions.CommitAction.executeFile(CommitAction.java:91)
    at org.wso2.developerstudio.eclipse.greg.manager.local.checkout.actions.BaseRegistryAction.run(BaseRegistryAction.java:49)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PluginAction.runWithEvent(PluginAction.java:251)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.handleWidgetSelection(ActionContributionItem.java:584)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.access$2(ActionContributionItem.java:501)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem$5.handleEvent(ActionContributionItem.java:411)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1053)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4066)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3657)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runEventLoop(Workbench.java:2629)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runUI(Workbench.java:2593)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$4(Workbench.java:2427)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$7.run(Workbench.java:670)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:663)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:115)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:369)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:619)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:574)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1407)
```

any idea?

Comment: It seems to be this specific operation is not allowed to perform on this resource. Has the necessary permission was provided?